# .net mySQL Connector for a 64 bit machine

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql

My local computer is 64 bit but the downloads for the .Net mySql connector found here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ are 32 bit.  I installed the 32 bit file however, whenever I try to input any new connector information after the 1st keystroke the box disappears.  So I'm assuming that it has more to do with my machine being 64 bit rather than 32...  Is there a 64 bit version of this connector?  Any other ideas?

UPDATE:

It is the Add a Connection box.

[image]

After I enter anything into any of the textboxes the above box just disappears.  Any ideas?

Comment: input new connector information where exactly ?

Comment: Which box disappear, where are you inputting something ? (and, atleast the MySQL.Data.dll is built for MSIL, thus processor independant. )

Comment: works fine in my visual studio 2008 (win7 64bit) - try connecting using toad http://toadsoft.com/toadmysql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your problem is due to a corrupt install of MySQL connector for .Net as described on MySQL website.  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23071

Their recommendation is to manually add the missing MySQL Data Provider entries in the Machine.config under DbProviderFactories section.

You could always try and un-install and re-install if you haven't tried that already.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I actually did update my machine.config file and then I also uninstalled and reinstalled the .msi file.  I restarted VS2010 and viola it worked!  So I guess it wasn't a 64 bit OS thing.  Either it was a bad install or I needed to update the machine.config.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm going to answer this question and then close it as although I couldn't get the real fancy Microsoft way of adding a datasource I did it the old fashioned way.  Not the super nice way but this was just me learning, so after you see this example please know that I'm a long way off still.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace MyFitnessApp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                MySqlConnection mss = new MySqlConnection("server=IP Address;Port=####;Database=db_name;Uid=userId;Pwd=password;");

                string strSQL = "";
                strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE;";

                MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL,mss);
                DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
                mda.Fill(myDS,"TABLE");

                this.GridView1.DataSource = myDS;
                this.GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I'd like to figure out how to call the connectionstring from the web.config but this is what I found in several examples.

What is ironic is that I'm much more comfortable in VB.Net and I'm learning C#.  The example I found was written in VB.Net and I converted it to C#.  (: