# Can't Connect MySQL to EF6 in VS

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

**The Basic Problem**

So it all boils down to the fact that the ADO.NET wizard crashes when I try to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model using a MySQL connection.  I know other posts have been made about this, but I have tried all their suggestions (days of trying) to no avail.

**My Environment**

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (v. 14.0.25431.01 U3)
- Entity Framework NuGet Package v6.1.3
- MySQL Community Server v5.7.16 @localhost
- MySQL Connector .NET v6.9.9
- MySQL.Data NuGet Package v6.9.9
- MySQL.Data.Entity NuGet Package v6.9.9
- MySQL.Data.Entities NuGet Package v6.8.3

**My Problem**

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application project which was just created.  The first thing I wanted to do was create a data model to connect to the MySQL database.  I do Add New Item>Data>ADO.NET Entity Data Model which brings up the familiar wizard. At the "Choose Model Contents" screen, I select EF Designer from database.  I click next, and reach the "Choose Your Data Connection" Screen and select my MySQL connection (which I can browse in Server Explorer, and on which "Test Connection" succeeds) and click next.  **It is at this point that the wizard crashes.**  Sometimes it will briefly flash the next screen of the wizard which shows a single radio button with Entity Framework 6 selected.  This disappears immediately and the wizard goes away without modifying the project.

**Things I've Tried**

- Reinstalling MySQL Server
- Reinstalling MySQL for VS
- Reinstalling MySQL .NET Connector
- Removing some unrelated VS plugins
- Updated all NuGet packages
- Creating a new DB schema to test connection
- Everything I've found on SO (usually something in Web.config)
- Reinstalling Visual Studio (twice!!!)

**The Question**

I know that MySQL has not left us without a way of creating a project that uses their database, which means that I'm doing something wrong.  Please help!

Comment: Is it just the wizard that crashes, or all of VS? Are there any memory dumps or exception reports?

Comment: I suggest *downgrading* some of those components, especially whichever is the most recently updated, as that's what likely caused this regression, and I doubt your MySQL server has anything to do with the crash.

Comment: @Dai it's just the wizard that crashes.  I have tried downgrading various components especially the NuGet packages to no avail.  Can you give me specific version combinations to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix it:

1. Open MySQL Community Installer and remove the MySQL Connector/NET Connector.
2. Close MySQL Community Installer and reopen it
3. Install the Connector/NET program again.

The reinstall failed once, then I relaunched and it worked.  Not sure why.  Feel free to comment with other ideas on fixes or causes.

This was somewhat helpful to me: [.net mySQL Connector for a 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860023/net-mysql-connector-for-a-64-bit-machine)